# Search for text in Calibri font in Word fails

Tags: fonts, ms-word, find

I am working on a macro that searches for text in certain fonts.

However, I am not able to find the text that is in Calibri font; search for the other fonts work fine.

I have tried it from the Find and Replace dialog also with the same results.

Why would this happen?

Comment: Please provide the code that's failing, as well as steps to reproduce the environment in which it's running. Also: is this document in an Asian or other non-Latin language? which version of Word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Office 2007 introduced the concept of "themes". At that time, documents automatically became linked to a "theme" and the theme font became the default font. Word recognizes two default fonts, one for the body and one for headings. These are listed in various places, such as the font list, as `+body` and `+heading`. Word looks up the font assigned to `+Body` or `+Heading`, but that font format isn't applied directly to the text, even though that's what is visible in, for example, the font list in the Ribbon.

In order to "find" text formatted with the body default you need to search:

```
Range.Find.Font.Name = "+Body"
```

This is the Word standard since Word 2007, but it can be changed, of course, by having a theme with a different font attached to the document. In order to determine what the default them font is, use:

```
Document.Documenttheme.ThemeFontScheme.MinorFont(msoThemeLatin)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Cindy. Your code Range.Find.Font.Name = "+Body" worked for me. I had tried Range.Find.Font.Name = " (Body)" which didn't work